# How to select a ListView item if I focus the TextBox inside that item?

Tags: wpf, listview, select, textbox, focus

I have a ListView like below. **Colum 2 is TextBox that I can rename item.**
When I focus to TextBox, I want the listview's row that contain that TextBox is selected, too. How can I do that? Thank!

```
<ListView x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="25">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Next}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Path}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Style

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you ethicallogics!